# Scribe and Spring Social integration for accessing LinkedIn APIs

Tags: integration, linkedin-api, scribe, spring-social

A couple of days back I was tasked with integrating Scribe and Spring Social for accessing LinkedIn APIs. Development environment being Windows, Spring and Java.

Spring Social's (spring-social-core-1.0.0.M1.jar) LinkedInTemplate uses org.scribe.extensions.linkedin.LinkedInBaseStringExtractorImpl. (Log messages showed "NoClassDefFoundError" for LinkedInBaseStringExtractorImpl) This class is present in scribe-1.0.7.jar but not in the latest jar i.e scribe-1.1.0.jar (downloaded at https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).

I couldn't find a way to fix this issue. But I was able to do a quick hack: on my local machine, I copied LinkedInBaseStringExtractorImpl from scribe-1.0.7.jar into scribe-1.1.0.jar. Everything works like a charm now.

I am curious to know if anyone else faced similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you say is right. [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) changed it's internals from 1.0 to 1.1 (and greater), though the public apis didn't change, some internals did, and this class `LinkedInBaseStringExtractorImpl` is no longer part of the lib.

Anyway, you don't need SpringSocial at all, check the [LinkedIn example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/LinkedInExample.java) to see how to consume LinkedIn's Api using just scribe.

Comment: For OAuth, scribe is the easiest no doubt! But Spring Social comes with nice wrappers such as [LinkedInTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/social/linkedin/LinkedInTemplate.html) which makes consuming data easier. Owing to convenience, I would suggest a combo of scribe + SpringSocial.